# The closure of a subspace of a normed space is NOT a subspace.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

-I think that the closure of a subspace of a normed space is not a subspace.

Let U be a normed space. U is a subspace of itself. The closure of U is not necessarily a subspace since U could be not closed.

..............

The proof of the statement "the closure of a subspace of a normed space is a subspace" is based on the following argument:

Let $U\subset V$. It is sufficient to prove that $\alpha x+\beta y \in \bar{U}$ where $\alpha, \beta$ are scalars and $x, y \in \bar{U}$. We know that $0 \in \bar{U}$ since $U \subset \bar{U}$. Since $x, y \in \bar{U}$ there exist $x_j, y_j \in X$ such that $x_j \rightarrow x$ and $y_j \rightarrow y$. Since multiplication and addition are continuous $\alpha x_j+\beta y_j \rightarrow \alpha x+\beta y$. Therefore, $\alpha x+\beta y \in \bar{U}$

..............

However, the vectors $ x$,$y$, and $\alpha x+\beta y$ are not necessarly in $V$.

Comment: The vectors $x$ and $y$ are in $V$ by assumption. Indeed, $\overline{U}$ means the closure of $U$ in the larger space $V$, i.e. the set of limits in $V$ made from sequences from $U$. It does not mean the completion of $U$, i.e. the unique complete space containing $U$ as a dense subspace.

Comment: $x,y$ and $\alpha x+\beta y$ are necessarly in V. The reason is that V is closed to itself and since $U\subseteq V$ and by the fact that the closure of a set $U$ is the smallest closed set containing $U$, we deduce that $cl(U)\subseteq V$.